# Import elements to a list with for loop

Tags: python, list, append

I am relatively new to Python and I am trying to add a random number (new_bandit) to the list new_bandit_probs if i == x. But if I print the new_bandit_probs list, I just get an empty list. Can someone help me out here?

```
import numpy as np

bandit_probs = [0.1, 0.4, 0.9] 
N_bandits = len(bandit_probs)
N_experiments = 1 
N_episodes = 100 
new_bandit = np.random.random ()
x = np.random.randint(0, N_episodes)
new_bandit_probs = []

def update_bandit_probs (bandit_probs, N_episodes, new_bandit, x, new_bandit_probs):
    for i in range(N_episodes):
        if i == x:
            new_bandit_probs.append(bandit_probs, new_bandit)
        return(new_bandit_probs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was not working because your `return` was set right after the first iteration in your `for` loop.

Plus, your `new_bandit_probs` was empty so stop after first iteration and return an empty list gives... an empty list. Some modification below:

```
import numpy as np

bandit_probs = [0.1, 0.4, 0.9] 
N_bandits = len(bandit_probs)
N_experiments = 1 
N_episodes = 100 
new_bandit = np.random.random ()
x = np.random.randint(0, N_episodes)

def update_bandit_probs (bandit_probs, N_episodes, new_bandit, x):
    for i in range(N_episodes):
        if i == x:
            bandit_probs.append(new_bandit)
            return bandit_probs

print (update_bandit_probs (bandit_probs, N_episodes, new_bandit, x))
```

Output:

```
[0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4026139866070344]
```

You can also do this in a single line:

```
def update_bandit_probs(v, n, c, x):
    return v+[c for i in range(n) if x == i]

print (update_bandit_probs(bandit_probs, N_episodes, new_bandit, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your return is inside the for loop. It returns immediately before i is incremented to 1 from 0. If `x!=0` then it will return empty list.

Move it out of the for loop:

```
def update_bandit_probs (bandit_probs, N_episodes, new_bandit, x, new_bandit_probs):
    for i in range(N_episodes):
        if i == x:
            new_bandit_probs.append(bandit_probs, new_bandit)
    return(new_bandit_probs)
```

Comment: Besides @ZLi pointed out the error, you have to change this line too:  new_bandit_probs.append([bandit_probs, new_bandit])  # append([a, b])